# Trouble with finding number of people who own a cell phone in certain year

Tags: exponential-function, education

I have a problem where a function is exponential and it comes with a table. I am trying to figure out how to find the number of people who own a smartphone in the Year 2020. I tried to use rate of change and other means, but I was stumped by this one question. Thank you

The value I am trying to estimate is $A_{0}$ and $P$

[table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yCfu.png)

[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gB7A.png) ← This is the original problem

Comment: What is the exact form of the function you are using? f(t) = ce^{at}$ for constants a and c?

Comment: $N(t) = A_{0}P^t$, $P$ is a constant, and $t$ is the number of years from 1977.

Comment: and if i understand the question right, you want to estimate $A_0$ and $P$? 
(Please add this detail and the form of the equation above to the question itself for other viewer's benefit)

Comment: Yes, that could be correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\widehat{y_t}$ be our estimate for the number in year t, and $y_t$ be the actual numbers (as per data). We wish to find estimates such that the total error between $y_t$ and $\widehat{y_t}$ is minimized.

One loss function that we could use over the errors is $|\cdot|^2$ (absolute value squared) such that $E = \sum\limits_{t=0}^{7} |\widehat{y_t}-y_t |^2$.

Then $A_0,P$ are minimizers of this loss. $A_0,P = argmin [E] = argmin[(A_0 P^t -y_t)^2]$. You can pass this to some numerical solver, and may find values like $A_0 = 2.122,P=1.1167$.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Year & Actual y & y Predicted & Error       \\ \hline
1977 & 2.1      & 2.12E+00    & 4.99E-04 \\ \hline
1978 & 2.4      & 2.37E+00    & 8.89E-04 \\ \hline
1979 & 2.6      & 2.65E+00    & 2.21E-03 \\ \hline
1980 & 3        & 2.96E+00    & 1.92E-03 \\ \hline
1981 & 3.3      & 3.30E+00    & 1.92E-06 \\ \hline
1982 & 3.7      & 3.69E+00    & 1.70E-04 \\ \hline
1983 & 4.1      & 4.12E+00    & 3.08E-04 \\ \hline
\end{array}

Once you have a model, it's straightforward to predict. You would predict $\widehat{y}_{2020} = A_0P^{2020-1977}$ (and obtain a value around 245 millions)

Answer (score 1):

You should post the full question and your attempt at a solution! As you have not stated the function I will assume it is of the form:
$$f(t)=ae^{bt}$$
where $a,b$ are constants.
$$f(0)=2.1=ae^{b(0)}\to 2.1=ae^0=a$$
Substituting the new value for a
$$f(1)=2.4=2.1e^b\to b=\ln(\frac{2.4}{2.1})$$
Now using both $a,b$
$$f(2020-1977)=2.1e^{(0.134)(43)}$$
$$f(43)=667.77$$